# Decode video in Cuda using a socket / memory instead of a file

Tags: c++, sockets, cuda

I am currently trying to decode video using cuda.  I have the cuda sample called `cudaDecodeD3D9`.  This sample uses a method called `cuvidCreateVideoSource` which takes a file pointer to the source video.  Is there any way to get Cuda to load video from memory / socket / stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I can't use `cuvidCreateVideoSource` method at all, but instead I can feed each frame of data directly to the cuda video parser by calling `cuvidParseVideoData`.

Here's an example of reading one frame from a file and feeding it to the cuda parser.  The file was created by me by writing the size of each frame to the file, followed by the frame data.  The file can easily be replaced with reading from a socket:

```
unsigned int size = 0u;
fread( &size, sizeof( unsigned char ), sizeof( unsigned int ), _file );

unsigned char *buf = new unsigned char[size];
fread( buf, sizeof( unsigned char ), size, _file );

CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET packet = {};
packet.payload_size = size;
packet.payload = buf;
cuvidParseVideoData( pCudaParser, &packet );

delete [] buf;
```

Comment: How do you extract the frame and frame size from the socket stream?

Comment: you'd have consult the API you're using to send and receive socket data.  It has nothing to do with Cuda Video, just basic sending and receiving data using sockets.