# Decoding H264 using CUDA from VLC via UDP

Tags: c++, cuda, video-streaming, h.264, vlc

I'm creating a video parser with **cuvidCreateVideoParser** and feed it a H264 UDP stream from VLC and it does everything that it's supposed to do. It calls all the handlers that in turn calls the decoder which in turn renders the frame to a Direct3D (**ID3D10Texture2D***) texture. The only problem is the texture is just random noise. If I send the parser data from file it is completely fine. Only if I stream it. I've even used live555 and sent the parser the data it gets from rtsp with even less luck, the **CUvideoparser** doesn't even acknowledge it's video data. I know I must be missing something simple here I just can't see it.

Basically the question is: How can I fill **CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET** from a stream instead of using **cuvidCreateVideoSource** which can only take a file

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here : [fill CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743928/decode-video-in-cuda-using-a-socket-memory-instead-of-a-file)

Also, you need to extract h264 Stream data from the rtsp Stream, before sending it to the Cuda parser. You can't send the rtsp stream has is to the cuda parser.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the link he has already extracted the frame so it works. If I send a stream over UDP that I've encoded with Cuda it decodes fine too. But I need it to work with rtp or rtsp and I'm using VLC to send it. I've used live555 to extract the H264 stream and I get no response from the parser, I think it extracts it too much and removes the NAL units the parser requires